# What kind of regular polygons should placed in this area?

Tags: geometry, polygons

A regular polygon has to be filled in at the vertex with angle marked $ (z \, 150^{\circ}) $ to form a 3D tessellation.

What kind of regular polygon should be placed in this area to complete the tesselation?

[image]

Comment: Which "area" are you referring to?  Are there any limitations on size of the polygons in relation to the picture?  Unless if you clarify the question it would appear as though the obvious answer is *every* kind of regular polygon provided it is made with small enough sides.

Comment: Do you maybe want to ask for which $n$ it is possible to place a regular $n$-gon in the plane such that $X$ is one of its vertices and it does not overlap the blue square or the green hexagon? Or maybe even, for which $n$ is there a perfect fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular $n$-gon has interior angle $\pi-2\pi/n$.

Here, to fit exactly, you want to get an angle of 150°, or $5\pi/6$.

Solve $\dfrac{n-2}{n}\pi=\dfrac56\pi$, and you get $n=12$.

Comment: does it have another way to find that?

Answer (score 1):

An interior angle of $150°$ implies an exterior angle of $180-150 = 30°$, so the regular polygon that would fill the $z$ angle on its own would have $360 / 30 = 12$ sides, since the exterior angles of every convex polygon sum to $360°$.

(If you are allowed two regular polygons to fill that angle, they would be a square and an equilateral triangle.)

---

Diagram for clarity - the exterior angle measures the change in direction at a corner for something traversing the perimeter of the polygon

[image]